# Proof of Tychonoff theorem with closed filter

Tags: general-topology, filters

In the following I post a proof of Tychonoff theorem with closed filters. It is based on the following theorem:

> Theorem. Let $X$ be topological space. Then following are equivalent
>
> (i) $X$ is compact space
>
> (ii) every filter of closed subsets of $X$  has non-empty intersection
>
> (iii) every ultrafilter of closed subsets of $X$ contains a minimal
>   element

The Tychonoff's theorem: If $X_i$ are compact topological spaces then product $\prod_{i \in I}X_i$ is compact.

Then proof of the Tychonoff's theorem, please can you tell me if it is valid proof? :

Assume $X_i$ compact and $\mathcal F$ ultrafilter of closed sets on $X = \prod_i X_i$. Define $\mathcal F_i = \{Y \subseteq X_i : \pi_i^{-1}Y \in \mathcal F \}$. Then $\mathcal F_i$ are ultrafilters of closed set in $X_i$ for every $i$ (I showed it also but will omit for brevity). The $X_i$ are compact therefore $\bigcap \mathcal F_i \neq \varnothing$ by assumption for all $i$. Define $x= (x_i)_{i \in I}$ where $x_i \in \bigcap \mathcal F_i$.

Assume $x= (x_i)_{i \in I}$  is not in $\bigcap \mathcal F$. Then for at least one $i$, $x_i \notin \pi_i \bigcap \mathcal F \subseteq \pi_i \pi_i^{-1}\bigcap \mathcal F_i = \bigcap \mathcal F_i$. This is a contradiction. Therefore $x \in \bigcap  \mathcal F$ and $\mathcal F$ non-empty.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say, if $x \notin A$ (where $A$ is that intersection) then there is some $i$ such that $x_i \notin \pi_i[A]$. This is quite false for sets in a product:

A simple counterexample for 2 sets: let $A$ be the diagonal in $X \times X$, then for all $(x_1,x_2)$ we have that $x_1 \in \pi_1[A] = X, x_2 \in \pi_2[A] = X$ but all points with $x_1 \neq x_2$ are not in $A$.

So you cannot show that $x$ is in the intersection using the projections in this way.

A totally different point: I don't see yet why your $\mathcal{F}_i$ are ultrafilters of closed sets. It is true that the $Y$'s are closed (as all $\pi_i$ are quotient maps), and they form a filter (as $\pi_i^{-1}$ preserves intersections and inclusions), but I don't see that they are maximal. On the other hand, you don't need it to get an $x_i$, as we just apply clause (ii) in your equivalence anyway.